# mongoose find() returns empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've cloned easyERP source code from git. They have these lines of code to generate some sort of schema. Here is whats happening

1. The connection opens fine
2. mainDBSchema is successfully generated
3. var main is also seems to fine and I get models and modelschema when I console this object.
4. The only problem is main.find().exec() return empty array. I tied all sort of hacks but nothing seem to work.

   ```
   var mainDb = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'mainDB');

   mainDb.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
   mainDb.once('open', function callback() {
   console.log("Connection to mainDB is success");
   var mainDBSchema = mongoose.Schema({
       _id: Number,
       url: { type: String, default: 'localhost' },
       DBname: { type: String, default: '' },
       pass: { type: String, default: '' },
       user: { type: String, default: '' }
   }, { collection: 'easyErpDBS' });

   var main = mainDb.model('easyErpDBS', mainDBSchema);

   main.find().exec(function (err, result) {
       if (!err) {
           result.forEach(function (_db, index) {
               var dbInfo = {
                   DBname: '',
                   url: ''
               };
               var dbObject = mongoose.createConnection(_db.url, _db.DBname);
               dbObject.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
               dbObject.once('open', function callback() {
                   console.log("Connection to " + _db.DBname + " is success" + index);
                   dbInfo.url = result[index].url;
                   dbInfo.DBname = result[index].DBname;
                   dbsArray[index] = dbObject;
                   dbsNames[index] = dbInfo;
               });
           });
       } else {
           console.log(err);
       }
   });
   });
   ```

Comment: Do you have any document in `easyErpDBS` collection in `mainDB` database?

Comment: Try adding a condition to `find` like this `find({}).exec(...)`.